# Android scoped storage on Android 11 - permission denied

Tags: adb, storage, android-11, android-13

The scenario is that one app is creating some files on its external storage `/sdcard/Android/data/myPackageName` and during testing automation I need to retrieve some files from that folder using `adb`.

The `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to `31`, and also uses:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For some reasons, the `adb pull` command doesn't work (permission denied) on Android 11 but it works on Android 13 (I used real phones **not emulators**)

These are the mount points:

**Android 13** (Pixel 5)

```
/dev/block/dm-40 on /storage/emulated/0/Android/data type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,flush_merge,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=32768,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,checkpoint_merge,fsync_mode=nobarrier,discard_unit=block)

id result:

uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),1078(ext_data_rw),1079(ext_obb_rw),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats),3009(readproc),3011(uhid),3012(readtracefs) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

**Android 11** (Pixel 5)

```
/dev/block/dm-12 on /storage/emulated/0/Android/data type f2fs (rw,lazytime,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noatime,background_gc=on,discard,no_heap,user_xattr,inline_xattr,acl,inline_data,inline_dentry,flush_merge,extent_cache,mode=adaptive,active_logs=6,reserve_root=32768,resuid=0,resgid=1065,inlinecrypt,alloc_mode=default,fsync_mode=nobarrier)
```

(the only differences are: `discard_unit=block` and `checkpoint_merge`)

```
id result:

uid=2000(shell) gid=2000(shell) groups=2000(shell),1004(input),1007(log),1011(adb),1015(sdcard_rw),1028(sdcard_r),3001(net_bt_admin),3002(net_bt),3003(inet),3006(net_bw_stats),3009(readproc),3011(uhid) context=u:r:shell:s0
```

I read a lot of posts, Android documentation etc and but I wasn't able to figure out the reason why this is happening. Why it works on 13 and not on 11? Any idea?

Comment: The reason why I posted the question here is because I feel that the issue is related to file systems, so not exactly related to Android development. Anyhow, I can move to SO no prob

Comment: Then it would be good to generalize the question, so instead of "my app" use "one app". Please name the phone models you have tested.

Comment: can you please update question with output of [id](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/help-i-uninstalled-com-android-shell-then-adb-package-manager-stopped-working-and-recovery-mode-started-to-acting-weird.4552753/post-88140841)? actually never tested A11+ but my assumption was `adb` can access the whole emulated storage /sdcard

Comment: answer updated. The only difference is that the output of `id` on Android 13 has these additional ids 1078(ext_data_rw),1079(ext_obb_rw), 3012(readtracefs)

Comment: 1078(ext_data_rw),1079(ext_obb_rw) are exactly the permissions missing. please double check the storage permissions for the app com.android.shell